# Taking user input in switch case

Tags: c, switch-statement

Can we take input in switch case ?
AS in here if i run the code, as it is it asks for a value of 'a' but it returns area as 0.
But if i define the value of 'a'  while declaring or anywhere outside of the switch case, it returns the correct value.

```
double a, area;
switch(ch)
{
    case 1: printf("equilateral triangle \n");
            printf("value of side \n");
            scanf("%f",&a);
            area= 0.433*a*a;
            printf("\n %f", area);
            break;

    default : break;

}
```

Comment: What is the type of `ch`? Please provide the signature of the function in which the above switch statement is contained. In the code you have provided is no `return` statement; it is a bit unclear what the overall context is.

Comment: Your question is fairly vague.  Are you getting the value of `ch` using a `scanf`?  Is `ch` a `char` or `int`?  If you are getting a value into `ch` using a `scanf`, you should have a character in `switch` statement, such as `case 'e': /* Equilateral triangle */`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You are getting wrong result because you are using wrong specifier for `double`. Use `%lf` instead (in `scanf`).

See the running code [here](http://ideone.com/LG7d7o).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with using the `switch`-`case`. However you have to use:

```
scanf("%lf",&a);
```

because `a` is declared as a double.

In the case of functions that take variable arguments like `printf()`, an argument of type `float` could be promoted to `double`.

However, C doesn't promote pointers and since `scanf()` takes pointers as arguments, it doesn't get promoted to a pointer to a double.

Answer (score 0):

Use %d at declaration,  %lf instead of %f (in scanf) and %f in printf().